# Unable to press 'E' key in bash when I add export EDITOR=vim in /etc/inputrc

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

When I add the line `export EDITOR=vim` into `/etc/inputrc` and start a new session in BASH, I am unable to press the <kbd>E</kbd> key on the keyboard. (Well, I *can* press it, physically, but nothing shows up in the terminal.) At first I thought I did something to the keyboard, but it works in all the other apps running. The peculiarity only occurs in the newly started BASH session. Furthermore, if I use the insert any string from the clipboard into the terminal, all the E's are ignored. Watch:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ xclip -o
cat /etc/inputrc
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ # I shall pr_ss Shift + Ins now:
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /tc/inputrc
cat: /tc/inputrc: No such file or directory
```

No 'e' in etc.

Interestingly, if I type `apt-g<Tab>`, it completes the command and the 'e' shows up:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ apt-g    # before pressing tab
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ apt-get  # after tab
```

Finally, This is the last bit of /etc/inputrc:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ xclip -o | xargs tail 

# for freebsd console
# "\e[H": beginning-of-line
# "\e[F": end-of-line

$endif

set completion-ignore-case on
export EDITOR="vim"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/inputrc` is used to customize *readline*, a system that is used by bash and some other programs to handle keyboard input. You can not define environment variables and do other Bash customization in this file.

Instead use `/etc/bash.bashrc` if you want to change some Bash settings for all users on your system or `.bashrc` in a user's home folder if you want to change the settings for just one user.

Comment: It seems the [recommended](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables) file in which to add the `EDITOR` variable is `/etc/environment`, not `bash.bashrc` (for system-wide settings at least). But thanks for the clarification anyway.